# Is there a way to automatically update the last slide once I change the first?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a PowerPoint presentation that I want to show every month (with monthly trendings) but there's 2 slides that are always the same: The first and the last.

Is there a way to automatically update the last slide once I change the first? I keep forgetting to change the last and it's always upsetting.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is unclear what you are asking. How are "*2 slides that are always the same*", yet you are asking how to "*update the last slide once I change the first*". Please use the [edit] feature to add details of what you are attempting and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

In a nutshell what you need to do is create a master slide that you then apply to the first and last slide of your presentation.

This master slide could contain everything that's in your first slide, or those elements that you change each month. Either way, once you've applied the master slide to your first and last slides, all you need to do is change the relevant master slide each month. Doing this will automatically update the first and last slide for you.

Just to be clear, what you're then updating each month is the master slide, not slide 1, and doing this will update any slide based on that master slide.

As you haven't specified which version of MS PowerPoint you're running (i.e. the Windows version or Mac version), below are some additional links that may be useful if you're not familiar with master slides:

- [PowerPoint for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-a-slide-master-d8d1c49d-d6f1-4b83-a4e7-34311a11b546)
- [PowerPoint for Mac](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjU34X5hYXQAhUJF5QKHXiQBxQQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.office.com%2Fen-us%2Farticle%2FModify-a-slide-master-ac4b72b2-b7e2-4b73-a6e0-70b6fec4be8d&usg=AFQjCNEx73KFEt3fBAHlaOI-MpX4XQvPWg)

Hope this helps! If you get stuck, let me know.

**[EDIT]**

Just realised you used the **microsoft-powerpoint-2010** tag, so you're obviously using the Windows version (the Mac version was 2011). However, I've left both links in my answer as it may help Mac users with the same query.

Comment: That already had crossed my mind but didn't seem it could work so I didn't try. After your answer I did try but maybe there's something I'm not doing as you did because each new slide I insert in the presentation (some months need some new slides but not all of them) appears with what the Master slide has. So, for each new slide, I have to remove the link to the Master slide. That's not very pratical...

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear you sometimes needed to add new slides. That's fine. First of all ensure that only the first and last slide have the master applied. Then, assuming you're using the slide sorter (left-hand side of screen) to add a new slide, as long as you're adding it anywhere **after** the second slide but **before** the last slide, then your new slide won't have a master automatically applied to it. (By default PowerPoint assumes you want the same master slide applied as the slide before.) Once you've added the new slide you can drag and move it to another spot.

Comment: Another option is to create a second master slide that you apply to all the slides between the first and last slide. Then if you prefer to use the New Slide button within the Home tab (in your ribbon), you can click on the bottom half of the button to view your master slide options and select the one you want to use for your new slide. Also, with this method, if you're using the slide sorter and insert a slide, it'll just adopt the second master slide instead (unless you're adding a new slide into the second spot of yoru presentation).